# "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xaa in position 1: invalid start byte" when scanning redis using pyton

Tags: python, python-3.x, redis, redis-cluster

I've redis with keys, hashes with both values and keys are also binary format.

I'm trying to scan the keys using python.

Code I'm using to scan is -

```py
import csv
import redis
import base64
from itertools import zip_longest

redisObj = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0, decode_responses=True)
searchStr = ""

redisObj.set(b'raj', b'kumar')
print(redisObj.get(b'raj'))


print("\n\nLoop through all keys in batches (using itertools)")
counter = 0
batch_counter = 0
print("Try scan_iter:")
for x in redisObj.scan_iter('*', charset='unicode_escape'):
    print(x)
```

When I run the code I get below exception -

> Loop through all keys in batches (using itertools)
>
> Try scan_iter:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/Users/myuser/Coding/redis-python-demo/just-print.py", line 17, in
>
> ```
>  for x in redisObj.scan_iter('*', charset='unicode_escape'):
> ```
>
> File "/Users/myuser/Coding/redis-python-demo/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/commands/core.py", line 3050, in scan_iter
>
> ```
>  cursor, data = self.scan(
>
>                 ^^^^^^^^^^
> ```
>
> File "/Users/myuser/Coding/redis-python-demo/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/commands/core.py", line 3025, in scan
>
> ```
>  return self.execute_command("SCAN", *pieces, **kwargs)
>
>         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```
>
> File "/Users/myuser/Coding/redis-python-demo/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 508, in execute_command
>
> ```
>  return conn.retry.call_with_retry(
>
>         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```
>
> File "/Users/myuser/Coding/redis-python-demo/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/retry.py", line 46, in call_with_retry
>
> ```
>  return do()
>
>         ^^^^
> ```
>
> File "/Users/myuser/Coding/redis-python-demo/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 509, in
>
> ```
>  lambda: self._send_command_parse_response(
>
>          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```
>
> File "/Users/myuser/Coding/redis-python-demo/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 485, in _send_command_parse_response
>
> ```
>  return self.parse_response(conn, command_name, **options)
>
>         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```
>
> File "/Users/myuser/Coding/redis-python-demo/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 525, in parse_response
>
> ```
>  response = connection.read_response()
>
>             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```
>
> File "/Users/myuser/Coding/redis-python-demo/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 493, in read_response
>
> ```
>  response = self._parser.read_response(disable_decoding=disable_decoding)
>
>             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```
>
> File "/Users/myuser/Coding/redis-python-demo/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/_parsers/resp2.py", line 15, in read_response
>
> ```
>  result = self._read_response(disable_decoding=disable_decoding)
>
>           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```
>
> File "/Users/myuser/Coding/redis-python-demo/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/_parsers/resp2.py", line 59, in _read_response
>
> ```
>  response = [
>
>             ^
> ```
>
> File "/Users/myuser/Coding/redis-python-demo/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/_parsers/resp2.py", line 60, in
>
> ```
>  self._read_response(disable_decoding=disable_decoding)
> ```
>
> File "/Users/myuser/Coding/redis-python-demo/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/_parsers/resp2.py", line 59, in _read_response
>
> ```
>  response = [
>
>             ^
> ```
>
> File "/Users/myuser/Coding/redis-python-demo/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/_parsers/resp2.py", line 60, in
>
> ```
>  self._read_response(disable_decoding=disable_decoding)
> ```
>
> File "/Users/myuser/Coding/redis-python-demo/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/_parsers/resp2.py", line 67, in _read_response
>
> ```
>  response = self.encoder.decode(response)
>
>             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```
>
> File "/Users/myuser/Coding/redis-python-demo/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/_parsers/encoders.py", line 43, in decode
>
> ```
>  value = value.decode(self.encoding, self.encoding_errors)
>
>          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xaa in position 1: invalid start byte

How can I fix this error?

Comment: What redis and Python are you using?  Works fine for me.